# Opening gnome-terminal and running script in tcl

Tags: tcl, gnome-terminal

When I try to execute below command it is showing Error like "extra characters after close-quote" but I gave it properly  & when i try to it in unix command line terminal is opening properly.

```
exec gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "bsub -Ip -n 1 -M <Memory> -q <queue_name> make"'
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue or is there any way to do the same thing ??

Edited ->  changed " from before sh to before bsub

Comment: Did you mean to have single AND double quotes? Tried removing either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl's quoting is *not* the shell's quoting. Tcl uses `{`…`}` like the shell uses single quotes, except that braces nest nicely. Nesting single quotes is a recipe for shell headaches.

```tcl
exec gnome-terminal -e {sh -c "bsub -Ip -n 1 -M <Memory> -q <queue_name> make"}
```

However, in this case I'd instead be tempted to go with this:

```tcl
set memory "<Memory>"
set queue "<queue_name>"
set command "make"

set bsubcmd "bsub -Ip -n 1 -M $memory -q $queue $command"
# It's much more convenient to build this command like this here.
# Otherwise you're doing lots of backslashes and so on and it's horrible and very easy to make bugs
exec gnome-terminal -e [format {sh -c "%s"} $bsubcmd]
```

The only really messy thing is that `command` and `bsubcmd` have to be built using shell syntax if you're passing spaces around. “Fortunately” you're dealing with `make` anyway, so you probably *really* want to avoid having spaces in names passed there.

Comment: Thanks Donald, Its working , Actually i am not using make Instead of make i am specifying tool name.

Comment: Why have "sh -c" at all?